# Show that $V$ is measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a Borelset and $f\colon B\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$ a non-negative measurable function. Show that
> >     $$
> > V:=\left\{(x,y)\in B\times\mathbb{R}: 0\leq y\leq f(x)\right\}
> > $$
> >     is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

My idea was to define for each $y\in Y$
$$
V_y:=f^{-1}([y,\infty])\times\left\{y\right\}.
$$
To my opinion this sets are Borelsets in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. But I think the problem is, that the union of all these sets $V_y$ is not, and so not V which is that union...

Comment: Since $f$ is measurable, the map $\phi:(x,y)\longmapsto f(x)-y$ is measurable from $B\times \mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then $V=\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^+)$.

Comment: By the way: What does it mean that $f\colon B\to\mathbb{R}_+$ is measurable? Related to which $\sigma$-algebras? . . .*confusing*

Comment: Do you have more context? Where does the question come from? The $\sigma$-algebras on the domain and the codomain of $f$ are just the [trace-$\sigma$-algebras](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Trace_Sigma-Algebra) of the ambient $\sigma$-algebras under consideration on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (I assumed these were Borel or Lebesgue).

Comment: Ah, thank you! So the $\sigma$-algebra on $B$ is $\left\{B\cap C: C\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$ and the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}_+$ is $\left\{\mathbb{R}_+\cap C:C\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right\}$. And your function $\phi$ is a sum of two measurable functions - and therefore measurable, too? So that $V$ is the fiber of a measurable set and therefore a measurable subset?  -- This is a very short proof, much shorter than the way that uses an algebraic induction. And very clever!

Comment: You mean $h\colon (x,y)\longmapsto y$ is continious and therefore measurable. $f$ is measurable, too. So $\phi=f-h$ is measurable.

Comment: Yes, it boils down to justifying that both are measurable.

Comment: But I still do not see completely why $\phi$ is measurable, sorry. And related to which sigma-algebras measurable?

Comment: I have to show that $(x,y)\longmapsto f(x)$ and $(x,y)\longmapsto y$ are both $\mathcal{A} - \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ - measuarable where $\mathcal{A}$ is the product sigma algebra on $B\times\mathbb{R}_+$, i.e. $\mathcal{A}=\Sigma_{B}\otimes \Sigma_{\mathbb{R}_+}$?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints to get you started.

1) Think of a way to approximate $f$ everywhere by simple functions $f_n$ (it'd be even better if it were an approximation from above, i.e. $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $f_n \geq f$ on all of $B$.

2) Let $V_n = \{(x,y) \mid 0 \leq y \leq f_n(x) \}$. Are these sets measurable?

3) When the $f_n$'s decrease to $f$, what is the relationship between $V_n$ and $V$? You should be able to obtain $V$ from a countable number of set operations on the $V_n$'s. This will imply the measurability of $V$.